# Best source to learn Kernel development programming?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have some experience with C/C++.
I have link+ IDE and Start with document this document(http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf)

Now it is based on 2.6 version and some headers have no functions as suggested by book. So, It is creating problem in testing the concepts.

Is there a way to get around with this problem?
Or any site that can provide kernel programming with all material ready(like OS to experiment and tutorial for Kernel programming with respect to that OS)

My end Goal is to learn about systems interfaces and network interface programming for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for network related kernel development guide then go for **Understanding Linux Network Internals** - O'Reilly Media. Its a really nice book.

Another interesting way to learn Kernel programming is taking [Eudyptulla Challenge.](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/). This will help you to contribute to open source also.

The best way to understand how any kernel subsystem works is by exploring the code itself which you can get here : http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.7/source/kernel across all versions.

Some other books :

[Linux kernel in a nutshell](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/)

[Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://www.flipkart.com/understanding-linux-kernel-3rd-3/p/itmdus6azbsdbxz8?otracker=from-search&pid=9788184040838&query=linux%20kernel&ref=b8d0a3b6-26ab-429e-968d-0ccabf72bb59&srno=t_2)

Comment: Thanks user 580082.
I think that will be a good start.
:)